# Deleted dynamic input appears again when another input is deleted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, input, material-ui

I have a list of dynamically created inputs which are saved in state. When i remove an input field, it is removed correctly,  However, when after deleting an input field i add a new input field, new value is not added to list, infact the input that was just deleted appears. I am using ingredient name as key, can it cause issue since it has spaces int it? Below is my code

```
    const [savedingredients, setIngredients] = useStat([]);
    const saveIngredient = async () => {
      var name = document.getElementById("ing_name1").value;
      reset({ ...getValues(), ing_name1: "" });
      var ingredients_array = savedingredients;
      ingredients_array.push({ name: name });
      var newArray = [...ingredients_array];
      setIngredients(newArray);
    };
    const deleteIngredient = (indexArray) => {
      var idNum = parseInt(indexArray) + 1;
      var nameId = "ing" + idNum;
      var checkIngredients = [];
      savedingredients.map((inst, i) => {
        if (i != indexArray) {
          checkIngredients.push({ name: inst.name });
        }
      });
      setIngredients([...checkIngredients]);
      enqueueSnackbar("Ingredient Deleted", {
        variant: "success",
      });
    };
    
    <List>
      {savedingredients.map((ing, i) => (
        <ListItem key={ing.name}>
          <Grid container spacing={1}>
            <Grid item xs={6} md={6}>
              <Controller
                name={`ing${i + 1}`}
                defaultValue={ing.name ? ing.name : ""}
                control={control}
                rules={{
                  required: true,
                  minLength: 3,
                }}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    fullWidth
                    id={`ing${i + 1}`}
                    inputProps={{ type: "text", disabled: true }}
                    {...field}
                  ></TextField>
                )}
              ></Controller>
            </Grid>
    
            <Grid item xs={3} md={2}>
              <IconButton
                onClick={() => deleteIngredient(i)}
                aria-label="close"
                sx={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  right: 8,
                  top: 8,
                  color: (theme) => theme.palette.grey[500],
                }}
                edge="end"
              >
                <CloseIcon></CloseIcon>
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton
                onClick={(e) => editIngredient(e, i)}
                aria-label="toggle action"
                sx={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  right: 30,
                  top: 8,
                  color: (theme) => theme.palette.grey[500],
                }}
                edge="start"
              >
                {stepAction == "Edit" ? <Edit /> : <Save />}
              </IconButton>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
```

Comment: Stop accessing DOM directly in react, it won't work.

Comment: Stop modifying the existing state like `ingredients_array.push`

Comment: thanks for your response. Can you please let me know what is the correct way to modify the state?

Comment: try searching *updating state beta docs* ...

Comment: I printed the state and state is updated correctly, only issue is with  inputs. I dont know how deleted inputs that are not in state appears again in input when new input is added